# php/mysqliのgroup by句で代わり目を感知するには

Tags: php, mysql

初歩的な質問ですみません。

(内容)|(日付)
A|2015/09/29
B|2015/09/29
C|2015/09/28

とデータベースにあり、出力時に日付ごとのインデックスを付けたいのですが
どうするのがベストプラクティスでしょうか

ページ表示的には

```
9/29
A
B

9/28
C
```

という並びにしたいと思います。

Comment: 何がベストかは何を優先させるかによると思います。PHPもカテゴリについているのでmysqlだけで処理を考えることは無いと思いますが、優先させるのは**処理速度**ですか？ **コードの簡潔さ**ですか？

Answer (score 1):

group by など使わずに
order by で日付でソートすればどうでしょうか。日付が変わる箇所はphpの方で判断すればいいと思います。